# Bake two NLA strips in a single animation

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

i'm getting mad with this.
I'm trying bake a single animation from different NLA strips, but i can't do it.
I imported a character with a skeleton and i added some animations with a retargeting from mixamo.
Now i have to mix 2 of those animations into one: i have an "injured-idle" animation and a "waving" animation and i want to bake those into a "injured-waving".
[image]
It works, i fused the two animation in the NLA editor, and i got the action that i want. But i can't bake it into one single animation, because when i try to bake action:
[image]
Blender gives me this error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\startup\bl_operators\anim.py", line 282, in execute
    actions = anim_utils.bake_action_objects(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\anim_utils.py", line 80, in bake_action_objects
    return iter.send(None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\anim_utils.py", line 111, in bake_action_objects_iter
    yield tuple(iter.send(None) for iter in iter_all)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\anim_utils.py", line 111, in <genexpr>
    yield tuple(iter.send(None) for iter in iter_all)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\anim_utils.py", line 281, in bake_action_iter
    pbone.keyframe_insert("location", index=-1, frame=f, group=name)
RuntimeError: Error: Could not insert keyframe due to zero NLA influence or base value


location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Help me please, i can't figure out what am i doing wrong.
Here is the link for the project: https://pasteall.org/blend/36f43fb650724e2ca7db8b4899b6fd32

Comment: Hello please share your file, only keep the armature and the 2 actions: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Ok, now is the rigth one, sorry

Comment: What do you mean, you didn't share the right one? In the one you share, I needed to demute the channels and select Chiamata1Mano.001 for the bottom one but I can't manage to bake either... I don't know where it comes from, I hope someone will tell

Comment: I shared a wrong one from WeTransfer, if you have seen the one from parteall.org it was the rigth one

Comment: Ok but I can't make it work either  :/  I hope someone will explain

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of your clips in the NLA editor is too short in frames. I tried to add keyframes in frame 60, but one of my clips was just 55 frames long. That generates this problem.

If you have the same error, do the following:
Go to the NLA editor

- Click once in the NLA editor to make sure it's active and press "N" to toggle the sidebar.
- Select a clip that is too short. In the sidebar, the options of that clip pops-up.
- Edit the "End Frame"value in the "Action Extents" section.
- Repeat this for all clips that are too short.

Now you can add keyframes again